# MediaPlayer cannot paused in Adapter Recyclerview with once Click Button

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

please help, I always experience errors here, I create mediaplayer in the audio list using 1 button, I have created the condition and isPlaying function on the mediaplayer in the adapter class, when the audio button is clicked successfully run, but when I click a second time, audio can not be paused, just repeat from the beginning, help me, what is the right solution?

this is my code:

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MurottalAdapter.MurotalHolder holder, int position) {
        Item item  = itemList.get(position);
        holder.titles.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.btnplays.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//I've tried replacing this with holder.itemview.getContext() and I put it outside the onclick method, but the problem is the same
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(view.getContext(),item.getAudio()); 
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        holder.btnplays.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled_black_24dp);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null){
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        holder.btnplays.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled_black_24dp);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try to move following code outside of onClick() method?

`mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(view.getContext(),item.getAudio());`

Comment: I've tried it, I put mediaplayer.create inside the onBindViewHolder method and outside the onClick method, but the page immediately forces close

Comment: Because of view.getContext(), your app is crashed.

Comment: Can you pass Context to adapter class from your activity and use this instead of view.getContext()? Like following comment code.

Comment: public YourAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }